# Is it possible to associate properties with properties with doctrine?

Tags: symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a database to implement with doctrine (and symfony6). A lot of entities, with a lot of properties. Some of theses properties are common to all entities, and I use PHP trait feature to handle that. My problem is that almost all properties (not entities... properties) need to have an associated string property. Is there a way to achieve that without having to declare another paired property for each existing property ?

For example, I have this entity (I'll have at least a dozen, even twenty, with differents properties):

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: NoteRepository::class)]
#[Index(columns: ["original_id"])]
#[ApiResource]
class Note
{
    use OriginalIdTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $content = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $target = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'notes')]
    private ?Person $person = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'notes')]
    private ?User $user = null;
```

and I'd like, for almost all these properties (content, target, person, etc.) having a paired string property (sourceContent, sourceTarget, sourcePerson) without having to declared them manually and being too verbose.

I was thinking about a unique json property by entity, json whose keys would be property names

```
{
"content" : "foo",
"target" : "bar",
...

}
```

don't know if there's better solutions

Thanks

Comment: Did you has a look at value objects and Doctrine embeddable? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/embeddables.html

Comment: Can you update your question with a specific example?  It is not clear to me why a property would need an associated string property.  It is possible to use PHP to create your mapping so maybe that would help.

Comment: COil not exactly what i'm looking for, but I didn't know this thing, can be interesting in another context, thanks !
@Cerad have updated my post, thank you :)

Comment: @arnaudbey Those pairs are value objects.  Using embeddables allow you to store them in one table instead of making a second table and using an association.  I suppose you could use json but it seems awkward and might make searching more difficult.  If it is important to track the source them maybe some sort of source/history table might be appropriate.  [PHP Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/) might be a better place for these sorts of discussions.